# writing desktop application for connecting with server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, desktop

I'm working on a server client base "Desktop Application". And what I want to do is this,
Client application sending some request code to server through internet(oh yes, these connections must be secured). and when server application gets this code it will again do some  work and gather some data.
And then server application will return those data again to the client application.

As I am new in this, I need to know, what kind of tools to use? 
Is eclipse good for that?
Where can I find good examples for writing client?
Where can I find examples for connecting client  with server side?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomend checking out apache [httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) it really helps when dealing with web APIs.